# Specify last_row and last_page values in Remote Pagination (AJAX) for Tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I'm using remote AJAX data loading (pagination) in Tabulator. Elasticsearch is running on the backend and I'd like to only return 10 results at a time, and then specify the last_row and last_page values to update the front-end Tabulator UI. I can't figure out how to set the last_page and last_row values using the remote AJAX response. Here is my Tabulator config:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        ajaxURL: "myurl",
        filterMode:"remote", //enable remote filtering
        pagination:"remote", //enable remote pagination
        sortMode:"remote", //enable remote sorting
        paginationSize:10, //set page size
        paginationSizeSelector:[10, 25, 50, 100],
        movableColumns:true,
        paginationCounter:"rows",
        layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
        resizableColumnFit:true, //resize columns to fit table width
        columns:[ 
            // Defined my columns here
        ],
        ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
            return response.data; 
        },
        ajaxURLGenerator:function(url, config, params){
            return url + "?params=" + encodeURI(JSON.stringify(params)); //encode parameters as a json object
        },
    });
```

Here is my Python server-side response to the AJAX request:

```
return JsonResponse({
            "last_page": int(res_count // size + 1),
            "last_row": int(res_count),
            "data": res
        })
```

I assumed I could add those values to the ajaxResponse, but I just get "tabulator.min.js:2 Data Loading Error - Unable to process data due to invalid data type ". Do I need to store the last_page and last_row values outside of the table definition in an HTML object and then manually update from within the ajaxResponse each time?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't seem to get Tabulator to recognize the last_page and last_row params in the ajaxResponse function, double check how you're initializing the Tabulator function. I had a typo.

```
pagination:"remote",
```

^^ Is incorrect. It should be:

```
pagination:true, //enable pagination
paginationMode:"remote", //enable remote pagination
```